# What are the units for the Husky turn rate? [husky_plugin.cpp]

Tags: ros, clearpath, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have modified the husky_plugin.cpp code such that it publishes its velocities to odom.twist.twist, for example:

odom.twist.twist.angular.x = odom_vel_[2];

When I command max turn rate, the odom topic reads 2.5, this is verified by the common.launch file for the husky:

param name="capped_turn_rate" value="2.5"

However, when I measure the turn rate of the vehicle in Gazebo at full speed, this "2.5" maps to roughly 10 rotations per every ~36-37 seconds. My guess was it is in units of degrees per update (40 Hz), however this does not change with  update rate. What unit is this angular velocity cap in?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195645/what-are-the-units-for-the-husky-turn-rate?-%5Bhusky_plugin.cpp%5D/) by [dnrohr](https://answers.ros.org/users/20552/dnrohr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is almost certainly radians per second. (2.5 radians per second is about 23 RPM)

[REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) defines metric units and radians as the standard units for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dnrohr](https://answers.ros.org/users/20552/dnrohr/) on 2014-10-22**:
I agree, however, where does the discrepancy between reported and measured coming from? Gazebo reports that it is running at full speed, in which case I would expect ~14 rotations in the same amount of time.